# Hiding columns in Twwdbgrid - Delphi 7 & Infopower 2000

Tags: delphi, datagrid

Hi I am building a project in which after I execute a query I show its results in a datagrid of Twwdbgrid type. My question is how to generally hide a column from this datagrid, when I use a filtering function.

I searched many days the internet and also tried to cast either the datagrid or the column to one of their parents - from which they inherit - in order to find a "Hide" or an "Enable"property, but it didnt' worked.

Some people in internet suggest to work with the "Selected" property of the Twwdbgrid. However this is a very complicate solution, specific when you want to reappear the hidden column after canceling the filtering action. So I am asking whether there is any more flexible and easy to implement way to achieve this task.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting the `UseTFields` property to `True` then manipulating the `Visible` property of the relevant field?

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for your answer. Is it possible to give me a sample, because I don't know how to reach the specific field. I mean that wwdbgrid.ColumnbyName[] is a function and returns a Twwcolumn object which does not have any Visible property.

Comment: I mean use the `Visible` property of the fields in the query the grid is linked to.

Comment: Even though in first place you are right, I believe that this can only happen in the sql query in design time and not in run time. Thus i can not use for example a filter from which to decide which columns i wan to see and which not. If i am wrong please correct me by providing me an example as our friend TDC. However there is an extra parameter to this problem.... when the query sends me the dataset i am creating dynamically one column - the first one - which counts increasingly the number of each record (1,2,3, etc), so i am not forced to use an integer as pm of my table, nor an index column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comments you can set the Grid's `UseTFields` property to True and then use the `TField` `Visible` property to control its display in the grid.

For example, supposing I had a table of contacts with Title, Firstname, LastName and Phonenumber.

My Query's `SQLText` property is set to `Select * From Contacts;`

I right-click my query at design-time and choose 'Add all fields'.

I now have 4 `TField` descendants `Query1Title`, `Query1FirstName`, `Query1LastName` and `Query1PhoneNumber`.

I can now toggle the visibility of the title displayed in a grid by writing the following code :-

`Query1Title.Visible := Not Query1Title.Visible;`

Comment: Hi Andy. Thank you for your example. It seems that gives a handy solution. However i have a small doubt about how to use it inside a function which i will generaly call to hide one of the columns. E.G: Function MyHide(column:string)                             in this function i will have somehow to concatenate the :datamodule2.Query1 with the appropriate field (e.g. Title) in order to have datamodule2Query1Title. Even though there is a fieldbyName property this doesn't have any Visible property itself. So it is difficult to implement

Comment: You don't specify what data access layer you are using but `FieldByName` usually returns a type of `TField` which does have a `Visible` property. There is also the `FindField` method which returns the same (if successful).

Comment: You are tottaly right, i just implemented it and managed to hide my dynamically created column and when i canceled my filter the column was back there. This case can be considered as solved.

Answer (score 1):

If best way to change the columns shown is to use the TwwDBGrid Selected property like so:

```
  // Clear the Columns
  grid.Selected.Clear;
  // Add the Columns you want shown
  // Selected.Add is a #9 (tab) delimited string with 3 to 4 parts
  //   First is the database column name
  //   Second is the column display size
  //   Third is the column heading (if multi-row heading you can use ~ to as a line break)
  //   Forth value Read-Only and is optional, it defaults to F (false)
  // Add a read-only column
  grid.Selected.Add('Field1'#9'10'#9'Column Heading 1'#9'T');
  grid.Selected.Add('Field2'#9'10'#9'Column~Heading~2'#9'T');

  // If you do not want a column, do not add it to the Selected list
  if ShowThisColumn then
   grid.Selected.Add('Field3'#9'10'#9'Column Heading 3')

  // You can also control/change the column types
  if ShowThisColumnAsACheckBox then
   begin
    grid.SetControlType('Field4', fctCheckBox, 'True;False');
    grid.Selected.Add('Field4'#9'10'#9'Column Heading 4');
   end;

  // Add a NOT read-only column
  grid.Selected.Add('Field5'#9'10'#9'Column Heading 5');

  // Then apply the selected column changes
  grid.ApplySelected;
```

Comment: Hi TDC, thank you for your reply. This is one way to solve my problem but how am i going to handle it through a filter dialog button. I mean that i want to be able to choose whether i will show all the columns or if i will show some of them. Also i was wandering if there is any work around using casting, so i could transform the datagrid to another type either - ancestor or child - then alter the "Visible" or "Enable" property of the chosen/s column/s to false and finally recast it back to datagrid type or use it as it is to show the result.